# Declare multidimensional Arrays C++ (compared to python)

Tags: c++11

coming from python I have a hard time understanding the data structure types and their declaration in c++.

To declare and populate a multidimensional array in python you just do as an example:

```
arr = [[],[]]

for i in range(2):
      arr[i].append(1)
```

What would be the equivalent in C++? Do I have to use vectors or arrays?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C/C++ are compile-time fixed size data structures. You declare them by

```
<data type> <variable name> <dimensions>;
```

<data type> can be anything you want.

<variable name> is also obvious.

<dimensions> need to be compile-time constants but can be as many as your target hardware supports, syntax is like [5] or [3][2].

You declare an array like

```
int numbers[5];
```

or

```
double weights[3][2];
```

Then, there are the containers from STL in C++. `std::vector<T>` behaves like a dynamically sized array, its counterpart the `std::array<T>` is a compile time array just like the one mentioned above but with container semantics which are a super set of plain arrays.

A multidimensional vector would be declared like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
```

This just declares a variable and initializes it - a two dimensional array to be precise - and you can later on resize it according to your needs.

Also note that vector will allow you to actually have jagged-arrays rather than the rectangular ones plain arrays always enforce. That is because you can push different sized vector to your v as elements.

You should read more about data structures, containers and algorithms in C++. C++ reference is a very good reference site. [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) page itself has many good pointers.

Comment: P.S.: C actually has variable length arrays, which do support dynamic sizes which are not required to be compile time constants. You can declare one like `int counts[n];`.